# Facebook “seen by” feature stopped working with only 61 members?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

How do I enable Facebook feature "seen by" to work? In the last week it stopped working and only shows the "seen by" icon, but not the people who've seen it. I have 61 members which is less than the 250 required before "seen by" is removed. Can someone help solve this issue? I have not found other posts helpful to fix this.

An image of the page is shown here showing "seen by" icon:

[image: Facebook image showing "seen by" icon]

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a 'Page' which is an admin of the group? I've found that when I link my 'Page' to my 'Group', that functionality breaks in the group.

If I leave the group as the 'page' and just have human admins it starts working again.

Not really a fix, but a troubleshooting step/workaround. I have a ticket open with Facebook but I'm not particularly optimistic about getting a reply.

Comment: Do you mean, leave the group or remove myself as admin? So there are no admins?